# scons - Recompile only specific portions of an application?

Tags: windows, dll, scons

This is my first time with `scons` and compiling in general.

[This application](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_desktop) had a problem [which was fixed by this guy here](https://github.com/freewizard/titanium_desktop/commit/d96d8754060686a95533a845f10f01cdb8fc81c6). Now I want to apply that fix manually but only recompile that specific bit of code. So:

1. followed [the instructions](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/building) and downloaded everything locally.
2. modified the 3 files accordingly
3. attempted to recompile:

   ```
   cd titanium_desktop/modules/ti.Network
   scons 

   scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
   File "C:\Python25\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-1.2.0\
   SCons\Script\Main.py", line 826, in _main
   ```

What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SConstruct file is the main SCons build script. Without it, SCons doesnt konw what to do.

I see from your commands that you are trying to do a build of a sub-directory which has a SConscript file, but not a SConstruct file. In this case, you need to tell SCons where the SConstruct file is. The most common way to do this is as follows:

```
# scons -u
```

This tells SCons to traverse up the directory hierarchy until it finds the SConstruct file.

You can find more SCons command line options [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html).

Comment: Thank you. After 2 hours of trial and error I eventually hacked my way into the SConstruct file and took out all unnecessary compilations.

Comment: Additionally you could have launched scons from the root project directory (where the SConstruct is) and only compile that dir, like this: # scons modules/ti.Network